# Exp-resso store Amazon S3

Tags: expresso-store

I'm looking for a way to sell mp3 files.

Will digital product downloads work if they are hosted on amazon S3 hosting service?

Comment: The file has to have a File Id in order to work through the download tag. So files hosted on amazon s3 will not work. It would be very nice if the system would accept the amazon s3 url or any other cloud hosted files. Is there a way to override this? There are many issues around uploading large files through the file system manager.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to.

When you create a product download you pass the custom field name of your file field to the `exp:store:downloads` tag which then will allow the user to download the item.

I have not tested this with a hosted service like S3 but I don't see why it wouldn't work. If for some chance it does not work you could use the `exp:store:orders` tag pair and something like [Link Vault](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/link-vault) to allow only users that have purchased an item to download the mp3 files.